# Why does django have both an authenticate method and a login method?

Tags: django, django-authentication

I'm going through an authentication tutorial and the author is using the `authenticate()` method to authenticate the credentials data from a login form. The result is assigned to a user variable like so

`user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)`

next: The user is logged in using `login(request, user)`

But why the 2 different methods? Isn't authenticating credentials supposed to be part of the procedure of loggin in? So why isn't that part handled by the `login` function as well? Or are there scenario's where you do want to use `authenticate` but not `login` ?

Also, what happens when the credentials are bad? Will user become null or will an exception be thrown?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`authenticate(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate) will **verify credentials**. It thus looks if the authentication backend has a user with the given credentials, and if so, return that `User` objects. Otherwise it will return `None`. But it will *not* log in that user. You can thus use that for sensitive methods, for example ask the password of a user that is already logged in, when that user plans to remove their account.

[**`login(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login) on the other hand, **logs in a user**. It will create a session with that user, and set the correct session variables. Note that *no* credentials are necessary for this. You can for example use that to give an administrator access to an account ("impersonate"), or to share a "virtual account" among certain people. Logging in a user does not *per se* requires to authenticate first.

While the two are thus much related, and one often sees a pattern where first a user is authenticated, and then logged in, that is not necessarily the case.

Answer (score 1):

`authenticate` confirms a user's credentials and returns the user object. You have now resolved a set of credentials to a user object. That does not automatically mean that you want to make that user the currently logged in user too. That is what `login` does, it updates the session to make that user "the logged in user". *Often* you'll probably want to do those two things together, but not necessarily. You may want to log in a specific user without any credentials, and you may want to verify a user's credentials without necessarily logging them in.