# Why do we use authenticate and not login directly in Django login system

Tags: python, django, authentication

Why do we use authenticate and not login directly, this is the code from my views.py:

```
def loginpage(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect(r'/')
        else:
            messages.info(request, "Username or Password is incorrect")
    return render(request, 'blogs/login.html')
```

Comment: `authenticate` checks if the credentials are correct. `login` only logs in the user. So you can use `login` if you want to login a user without checking the credentials (or perhaps check these in another way like a one-time-password).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59412525/67579